# How can I verify that QML elements are loaded or not?

Tags: qml

I have the following code snippet in QML, but I doubt statements inside Repeater element is not executed.

Is there any way through which I can debug these, I know that there is a log property present for the Repeater element but I am not sure how to use it.

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    id: screen

    width: 1024
    height: 600

    /*Loading Screen*/
    Interactive {id: interactive}
    Loading {id: loading;}

    /*Application Components*/
    Pif {id: pif}
    Config {id: config}
    Media {id: media}


    Repeater {
        model: config.launchers
        delegate: Loader {
            id:loader
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: file
            onStatusChanged: {
                if (loader.status == Loader.ready)
                {
                    loading.opacity = 0
                    loading.visible = false
                }
            }
        }

  }

    Fullscreen {id: fullscreen}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-component.html)

```
Repeater {
    // ...
    delegate: Loader {
        id:loader
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("Loader", loader.status)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My loader is not loading. Even its not loading with the above code snippet provided by you. Do you know what is causing the problem? Thanks, in advance !!

Comment: Assuming `Repeater ` is a `ListView`, and `delegate` is an alias to ListView.delegate, it should work.. Does the model being populated with any items?

Comment: Yes the model is populated & i am using XmlListModel.